# Index and match function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table

```
Budget  Duration    Revenue SEO
160 3 Months    $100K   $0
320 3 Months    $200K   $0
480 3 Months    $300K   $0
640 3 Months    $400K   $0
800 3 Months    $500K   $0
960 3 Months    $600K   $0
1120    3 Months    $700K   $0
1280    3 Months    $800K   $0
1440    3 Months    $900K   $0
1600    3 Months    $1M $0
3200    3 Months    $2M $0
4800    3 Months    $3M $0
6400    3 Months    $4M $0
8000    3 Months    $5M $0
16000   3 Months    $10M    $0
160 6 Months    $100K   $160
320 6 Months    $200K   $160
480 6 Months    $300K   $240
640 6 Months    $400K   $320
800 6 Months    $500K   $400
960 6 Months    $600K   $480
1120    6 Months    $700K   $560
1280    6 Months    $800K   $590
1440    6 Months    $900K   $720
1600    6 Months    $1M $640
3200    6 Months    $2M $1,120
4800    6 Months    $3M $1,200
6400    6 Months    $4M $1,600
8000    6 Months    $5M $1,600
16000   6 Months    $10M    $1,600
160 9 Months    $100K   $160
320 9 Months    $200K   $200
480 9 Months    $300K   $300
640 9 Months    $400K   $400
800 9 Months    $500K   $440
960 9 Months    $600K   $530
1120    9 Months    $700K   $625
1280    9 Months    $800K   $715
1440    9 Months    $900K   $815
1600    9 Months    $1M $720
3200    9 Months    $2M $1,280
```

Matching Duration and Revenue I need to display the SEO column's value.....please revert ASAP

Comment: What have you tried? Your approach sounds a bit demanding. This is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 2):

Use an Index/Match combo if your values are mutually exclusive:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH($G$1&$G$2,INDEX(B1:B100&C1:C100,0),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey this is very helpful.....but i apologize for demanding an answer instead of requesting.....however thanks a lot for your help.....happy new year

Comment: learn about the site an how it works. It will benefit YOU in the long run. Be polite, acknowledge that everyone here is a volunteer, working without pay. If a post answers your question, mark it as the answer. That is your way of saying "thanks" for an answer that has helped you.